# WordPress Taxonomy Structure For Laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am developing a taxonomy system (tags, categories, and attributes) with Laravel. Currently in my database I have the following tables, "terms", "term_relationships" and "products". The "term_relationships" table being the pivot table. However, with multiple taxonomies (e.g. categories, tags and attributes), how can I store the taxonomy names without getting them confused between categories, tags or attributes. I see that WordPress uses a 4th table named "term_taxonomy", however I am unsure of how the 4 tables relate to each other.

Would someone be so kind as to enlighten me on this subject providing the best solution to implement such a taxonomy system.

Thank you.

Comment: In an Eloquent structure, you'll likely want a separate `Taxonomy` model with a `taxonomy_id` relationship on the `Term` model, or you can register Taxonomies as a Configuration option and simply store the relative string in the `Term` object as a `taxonomy` column. Either approach should help you separate similarly named terms from their respective taxonomies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can help, I created this package : https://github.com/codiiv/laravel-taxonomies  and it's based on the  3 table structure in Wrordpress, but I combined them into one table rather!

Comment: Looks perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I will be adding more features in the coming commits of next week. It's still in infancy but I am already using it in projects